# Can 18.04.1 be installed without access to internal hd?

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, live-usb

I'm trying to install 18.04.1 on a laptop with an MMC harddrive, using USB Live on a thumb drive.  The ultimate goal is to dual boot from an external drive, or perhaps a micro SD card.

The live image won't load, apparently due to errors in initializing the MMC and reading/writing? to the MMC.  (the MMC works fine with Windows 10).

**Is there a parameter which could be added to the grub entry which would exclude the MMC from access by the installer?**

For reference, here are the error messages which first occur when selecting the "try Ubuntu" entry in the USB stick menu:

mmc_select_hs400 failed, error -84
error -84 whilst initializing MMC card

error -110...

and similar errors later addressing "mmcblk0"

**Update Sept 9, 2018**
This is relevant background only:
It appears that you cannot reliably run the live USB in 18.04.1 if your "main" disk is not accessible.  I've tried several approaches -- and captured the dmesg log twice.  Even when you have two USB drives, both discovered -- one the Live USB, and the other as the installation target -- it appears that if you have errors or access issues on the main disk (in my case an MMC), the install attempt will probably fail. One form of failure is an infinite loop attempting to access the MMC, the other form is the MMC not accessible, the live USB still getting to the point of recognizing all the other hardware, and then finishing with

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

BTW, once I managed (by luck) to install 18.04.1 on an SD card, the installation had no trouble accessing the main drive (MMC).  Additionally, Windows 10 has been completely happy with the MMC through all my attempts.

Comment: Try disabling fast boot in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that -- but still had problems.  Since I wrote this question, I tried just to capture the errors, and I found that itermittingly, couldl get all the way to live screen.

Comment: From there I managed to put Ubuntu on an micro SD, and am now typing this in Ubuntu.  Here is what I did on the SD -- I used the whole thing, and put boot records on the SD itself.  So, now, I can boot the machine just using the SD, by using the boot menu in the BIOS.  (the MMC did not even appear in the list of available drives)

Comment: There are other possibilities. A. The MMC is formatted as a dynamic partition by Windows. B. The MMC is defined as a RAID drive in UEFI.

Comment: so in fact your problem is now solved?

Comment: no, the problem is not solved.  I have an installation that works, but I still cannot run Live USB reliably.  This means, among other things, that I will not invest in a more reliable external disk for an Ubuntu installation on this computer, because I don't have a reliable way to install Ubuntu on this computer

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem ([Installing Ubuntu on lenovo 130s / trouble eMMC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125447/installing-ubuntu-on-lenovo-130s-trouble-emmc)) and in my case Ubuntu in live mode finally comes up!
It takes for a long time (~50minutes) with emmc error messages from time to time - but boots up finally. 
I can't install ubuntu on the eMMC, but that's not what you intend anyway if I get your question correctly.
So just allow it long enough to finish the boot process. hope that helps