# Installing Ubuntu on lenovo 130s / trouble eMMC

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, ideapad, emmc

I have trouble installing ubuntu 18.04 on a lenovo ideapad 130s.

When the LiveUSB (created by rufus) is booting it takes forever to boot the GUI {around 50 min!} with cqhci timout for tag 4 and tag 26 errors. 
Finally, when I try to install Ubuntu on the eMMC libparted gives an ERROR fsyncing/closing /dev/mmcblk0 Input/output error during installation.

here is a part of the syslog ( the error repeats for the first 1400 seconds!)

> `Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.003529] scsi host0: ahci
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.007126] mmc0: CQHCI version 5.10
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.012278] scsi host1: ahci
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.013217] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xa131c000 port 0xa131c100 irq 126
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.014119] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xa131c000 port 0xa131c180 irq 126
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.015145] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:00:1c.0] using ADMA 64-bit
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.080717] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1e3d, idProduct=2092, bcdDevice= 1.00
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.081597] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.082427] usb 1-1: Product: Flash Disk
>
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.083242] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: CBM
>
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.084041] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 101528007B4E6801
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.096905] mmc0: Command Queue Engine enabled
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.097723] mmc0: new HS400 MMC card at address 0001
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.101367] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 MMC32G 28.5 GiB 
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.102254] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 MMC32G partition 1 4.00 MiB
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.103144] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 MMC32G partition 2 4.00 MiB
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.103999] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 MMC32G partition 3 4.00 MiB, chardev (240:0)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.212203] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.332537] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.333370] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.361402] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c024, bcdDevice= 1.10
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.362230] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.363050] usb 1-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.363857] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Realtek 
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.364705] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.492193] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.660099] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5627, bcdDevice= 0.01
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.660987] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.661861] usb 1-8: Product: EasyCamera
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.662717] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: 8SSC20R48189A2YD8AW9665
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.663568] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 200901010001
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.672226] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.673367] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.674326] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    3.676766] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.704779] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     CBM      Flash Disk       5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.706107] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.708094] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 16367616 512-byte logical blocks: (8.38 GB/7.80 GiB)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.709129] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.710025] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.710185] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.711070] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.717790]  sda: sda1 sda2
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.721294] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.722965] random: fast init done
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.790961] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.790983] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [    4.791847] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.480215] mmc0: cqhci: timeout for tag 29
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.481069] mmc0: cqhci: ============ CQHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.481867] mmc0: cqhci: Caps:      0x000030c0 | Version:  0x00000510
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.482669] mmc0: cqhci: Config:    0x00000101 | Control:  0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.483458] mmc0: cqhci: Int stat:  0x00000000 | Int enab: 0x00000006
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.484236] mmc0: cqhci: Int sig:   0x00000006 | Int Coal: 0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.485015] mmc0: cqhci: TDL base:  0x6ef19000 | TDL up32: 0x00000001
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.485781] mmc0: cqhci: Doorbell:  0x20000000 | TCN:      0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.486519] mmc0: cqhci: Dev queue: 0x00000000 | Dev Pend: 0x20000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.487265] mmc0: cqhci: Task clr:  0x00000000 | SSC1:     0x00010008
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.488011] mmc0: cqhci: SSC2:      0x00000001 | DCMD rsp: 0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.488741] mmc0: cqhci: RED mask:  0xfdf9a080 | TERRI:    0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.489483] mmc0: cqhci: Resp idx:  0x0000000d | Resp arg: 0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.490220] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.490963] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.491706] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007080 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.492438] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00018000 | Trn mode: 0x00000010
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.493178] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0001 | Host ctl: 0x0000003c
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.493904] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000b | Blk gap:  0x00000080
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.494621] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.495326] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000e | Int stat: 0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.496031] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff4000 | Sig enab: 0x02ff4000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.496730] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.497420] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x546ec881 | Caps_1:   0x80000807
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.498095] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000d1a | Max curr: 0x00000000
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.498789] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0xffffffff
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.499477] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x320f5903 | Resp[3]:  0x00d04f01
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.500151] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000008d
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.500798] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000016f37420c
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.501465] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [   64.502186] mmc0: running CQE recovery
>   Mar 17 10:00:07 ideapad-S130 kernel: [  125.920199] mmc0: cqhci: timeout for tag 29
>   Mar 17 10:00:0`

The eMMC is a HS400 (according to dmesg) with 32GB.
lsblk shows mmcblk0, mmcblk0boot0, mmcblk0boot1

gdisk /dev/mmcblk0 shows MBD, BSD, APM, GPT as not present but also a Read Error 5

fdisk just shows "cannot open /dev/mmcblk0 Input/output error"

I know the installation Medium works since I installed ubuntu using the same stick on a Lenovo 120s with an SSD. 
So my guess is that it has to do with the eMMC used in the 130s in combination with Linux or the installer.
eMMC is fine since booting into windows 10 home works w/o any problems.

changed windows 10 home from S mode into non S mode.
I tried to disable fast reboot in windows 10 home (to avoid lock of emmc by windows).
Tried different settings in UEFI (Legacy mode, UEFI first etc..) but I guess it should work with the same settings as the 120s does.

Is there an issue with the MMC drivers or the kernel? 
Anyone had similar problems? Looked for other answers but didnt find any.

Also tried the current fedora just for cross check - 
two different USB sticks
ISO mode and DD mode in rufus for writing the USB stick 
but same prob.

I'm stuck and would appreciate your help! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good job!
Also what worked for me if you wanted a 64-bit:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1462188/1679471

Answer (score 0):

Tried a 32-bit image of Ubuntu 16.04 and that works!

Immediately boots in the GUI, full access to /dev/mmcblk0, no problems.

So it's either the new kernel version or the 32- vs the 64bit version.

( the celeron n4000 in the lenovo 130s is a 64bit cpu, but read things I don't care enough to understand about 
32-bit UEFI in combination with 64bit CPU in some devices)

So solved for me now since I know it's a Ubuntu bug and not the device.